# Data transformations for non-normal data

Tags: time-series, repeated-measures, data-transformation

I conducted an experiment using a factorial design and have to analyze some of the variables using a repeated measures in time, which I am analyzing in SAS. I have never used a repeated measures ANOVA before. I work with biological systems and unfortunately they rarely meet the assumptions needed to run statistical analysis and I cannot get my data to meet the assumptions of normality despite trying a number of transformations such as inverse, log, squared, cubed, square root, three quarters root, and others. The data doesn't appear to be that bad and appears to be influenced by just a few points. When I check for normality all are P<0.0001. I have attached a few examples of what the residuals look like. Any help on what transformations I can try, or new direction to go would be greatly appreciated.

I also have included a little data to better understand the set up and code. "S" and "N" are my factors, each having two levels. Tank is my unit/subject from which I measured the variable every week (0-4).

```
week Block  tank    S   N   variable
0   E   1   1   1   14.1
1   E   1   1   1   17.4
2   E   1   1   1   10.8
3   E   1   1   1   19.4
4   E   1   1   1   21.1
0   E   2   2   2   14.4
1   E   2   2   2   17.4
2   E   2   2   2   10.7
3   E   2   2   2   19.2
4   E   2   2   2   21
0   D   3   2   2   14
1   D   3   2   2   17.4
2   D   3   2   2   10.8
3   D   3   2   2   19.3
4   D   3   2   2   21.1

Proc Mixed data=meso;
  class tank S N week;
  Model variable=  week S N  week*S week*N S*N week*S*N;
  Repeated week/ Subject=tank Type=CS;
  Random Block;
run;
```

[image: residuals of variable 1]

[image: residuals of variable 2]

Comment: Your residuals don't have to be exactly Normal, but reasonably symmetric with few outliers would be nice.  Your abbreviations suggest you are looking at wastewater quality parameters.  It almost always is the case that logs, and sometimes square roots, are better options for analysis than the raw values. That is exceptionally clear for NTU, where the linear change of residual spread with fitted mean indicates a log should work well.

Comment: I've heard that before and this is where I get confused. If it just has to be reasonably symmetric why do we have these assumptions and check them with tests? What defines reasonably symmetric? I am a very by the book guy and so I have trouble understanding how this works.

Pretty close with the waste water. I am actually looking at water quality metrics associated with fish growth.

Comment: Statistics is not an exact science.  The assumptions we make like normality are idealizations.  Real data are almost never a sample from a normal distribution. But if it is generated from a distribution which is close in the sense that Bill Huber suggests a statistical test is not likely to tell unless you have a very large sample.  We do the tests so that we can perhaps look for a nonparametric  alternative if the data is so far different from normal that we reject. Also no test is foolproof.  In hypothesis testing we have to concede that type I and type II errors are always possible.

Comment: People with a strong mathematical or scientific background can find this hard to accept at least at first.  Probability theory provides the tools that statisticians need. But probability theory is strongly mathematical and measure theoretic.  Probability theory can be viewed as a branch of mathematics.  We theorems and lemmas that are proved rigorously. But when we do data analysis there is not a unique approach.  Two different statistical models may both give an adequate fit to our data.

Comment: On the other hand major theorems in probability are discovered through observation of data.  The central limit theorem could have been discovered by observation.  Later on the probability theorist formalize this mathematically and search stronger more generalized results and if possible get necessary a nd sufficient conditions for the result to hold.  With the Central Limit Theorem the De Moivre-Laplace version came first probably because binomial outcomes were common.  and easily observed. This was generalized to just require the Lyapanov criteria and more general still with Lindeberg-Feller.

Comment: @MichaelChernick What is considered a large sample from a statistical point of view? In my stats class anything less than 30 was a small sample. My current experiment has 200 data points. Is that large enough that a test will always detect it as different from normal? I know there is a nonparametric alternative but it is not very good.

Comment: There is no cut and dry answers.  In some instances rules of thumb can be used. But they can get misused in others. I think many times we characterize samples as small or large because we don't have confidence in supplying a number.  I think it would help if you look at a book like Gerald van Belle's book that has the title "Statistical Rules of Thumb". now in its second edition published by Wiley (2008).  This is the only book I know of that seriously addresses this issue.

Comment: Will do. Thank you very much @MichaelChernick and whuber